# R JAGS (Bayesian modelling) random walk prior

Tags: bayesian, jags

I am trying to estimate force of infections through JAGS model.
I am trying to specify the distributions as random walk prior but the compilation keep fails.

my codes are below:

```
jcode <- "model{ 
    for (i in 17:20){
    n.pos[i] ~ dbinom(seropos_est[i],N[i]) #fit to binomial data
    seropos_est[i] = ifelse(age[i]> (2019-delta3), 1-exp(-lambda1),
        ifelse(age[i]> (2019-delta2) && age[i] < 30, 1-exp(-lambda1-lambda2),
        ifelse(age[i]> (2019-delta1) && age[i] < 14, 1-exp(-lambda1-lambda2-lambda3),
        0)))
    # time-varying catalytic model
    }
  lambda1  ~ dnorm(0,1)       #uninformative prior
  lambda2  ~ dt(lambda1, sigma, tau)
  lambda3  ~ dt(lambda2, sigma, tau)
  delta1  ~ dunif(2006,2019)
  delta2  ~ dunif(1990,2004)
  delta3  ~ dunif(1960,1988)
  sigma   ~ dnorm(0,1)
  tau     ~ dunif(0,1)
}"
```

An error message is like this

```
Error in jags.model(textConnection(jcode), data = jdat, n.chains = 4,  : 
  Error in node lambda2
```

Hope there's anyone knows about this error!

Comment: The parameter you have for `sigma` is the precision and as such has to be strictly positive, so the `dorm(0,1)` prior won't work.  You could use the top half of the normal `dnorm(0,1)T(0,)` or perhaps even better a distribution that is naturally bounded at zero, like `dgamma()`.